# Global header for AngularJS post

Tags: jquery, angularjs, http-headers

How can I create a global header similar to jQuery using AngularJS?

Something like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('__RequestVerificationToken', 'abc123');
    }
});
```

Right now I doing this:

```
$http({
    url: 'mysite.com/',
    method: 'POST',
    data: 'data',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
})
```

Comment: read section Setting Headers in docs

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wow ... It was just in front of my face!

Reading the section "Settings headers" as @charlietfl said ... it's really simple.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http

> Setting HTTP Headers The $http service will automatically add certain
>   HTTP headers to all requests. These defaults can be fully configured
>   by accessing the $httpProvider.defaults.headers configuration object,
>   which currently contains this default configuration:
>
> To add or overwrite these defaults, simply add or remove a property
>   from these configuration objects. To add headers for an HTTP method
>   other than POST or PUT, simply add a new object with the lowercased
>   HTTP method name as the key, e.g.

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = { 'My-Header' : 'value' }
```

**Example Code**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['app.controller', 'app.service']);

app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = { "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest", "__RequestVerificationToken": $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val() };
});
```

Comment: But we need to do this for all modules. Is there any way to set it globally for all modules?

Comment: Didn't test it .... but I think it might work ... module.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
   $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = 'my stuff'
}]);